# String expresion in Solaris not working

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

Does somebody know why the next code doesn't works in Solaris with KShell?

```
DATE=20180420
MONTH=`expr ${DATE:4:2}`
echo MONTH=$MONTH
```

It returns:

```
${DATE:4:2}: wrong substitution
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? Can you do `echo $SHELL` and let know what is shown? and also the output of `"$SHELL" --version`

Comment: If its `ksh` can you do `echo $KSH_VERSION` and show it?

Comment: echo $SHELL returns /bin/ksh   echo $KSH_VERSION returns nothing

Comment: Can you try `ksh --version` and show what's seen?

Comment: ksh --version returns nothing (¿?)

Comment: Do you get something with `echo ${.sh.version}`?  Also, having a look at the man page might give a hint. The problem with ksh is, that there are so many variants around, each being a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell scripting syntax are different in different shell and hence you are getting this issue. If you run it in `bash` sell it will work for you in Solaris. So better change your script like below:-

```
 DATE=20180420
 MONTH=$(echo $DATE | cut -c 5-6) 
 echo MONTH=$MONTH
```

The good thing is that it will work in all the shell in unix. Some more option here:-

For day:-

```
day=$(date +%d)
```

For year in yy format:-

```
year=$(date +%y)
```

For year in yyyy format:-

```
year=$(date +%Y)
```

You can put the below line at the top of your script which will fix your issue.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 DATE=20180420
 MONTH=`expr ${DATE:4:2}` 
 # or MONTH=$(expr ${DATE:4:2}) 
 echo MONTH=$MON
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response but, we are forced to work with kshell and the date is not the date of the system, is another date; for example: SOME_DATE=20160224     ...   This works: MONTH=$(echo $DATE | cut -c 5-6)

Comment: I mean: MONTH=$(echo $SOME_DATE | cut -c 5-6)

Comment: @JLLMNCHR, I have modified my answer based on your advice so that it should help some one.

Comment: @JLLMNCHR, Thank you.